# New Gboard dual language suggestions, how do I disable it?

Tags: languages, gboard

Recently the Google keyboard has activated suggestions for both of my selected languages.  This is a real nuisance since the suggestions are a mess IMO.

How can I disable it and go back to switching languages manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the multilingual suggestions is a new feature in Gboard (ref: [Gboard, now available for Android - Official Google Blog](https://blog.google/products/search/gboard-now-on-android/).

**Steps to enable/disable it:**

1. Open **Gboard's Settings**
2. Select **Languages**
3. Select a language
4. On supported languages, below *Language settings*, tap **Multilingual typing** to enable/disable it. When enabled, you can check/uncheck other languages individually.

**Note**: the preference is *not* symmetric. When you have 2 languages that are supported for multilingual typings, you can disable it on language A while having it enabled on language B with A.

Answer (score 13):

> How can I get back to manually switching between languages? Is there a
>   setting I've missed, or do I have to roll back to an earlier version?

On the the keyboard options you'll find settings for *Languages*, *Preferences*, *Theme*... and in *Text correction* you'll find the toggle you're looking for: *multilingual typing*.

Comment: Latest Gboard moved the _multilingual typing_ toggle to _Languages > Language_. There, each language defines whether it uses multilingual typing or not, and with which languages.

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick access to Languages menu

In the latest versions of gboard the multilingual settings have moved to the *Languages* submenu which can be quickly accessed by long tapping the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key, and then picking <kbd>LANGUAGE SETTINGS</kbd> in the popup that appears (at the very bottom, below the language list).

Now, tap each language one by one, and uncheck the multilingual typing option.

---

#### Access gboard Languages from the Settings

You can also access the *Languages* menu from settings:

Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Languages & Input</kbd> > <kbd>Virtual keyboard</kbd> > <kbd>gboard</kbd> > <kbd>Languages</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Go to Gboard keyboard settings/Text correction and Untick Show suggestions

Comment: I don't want to disable suggestions, I want to disable the multi-lingual suggestions.