# How do I enable multilingual suggestions in GBoard

Tags: gboard

I switched to a different phone recently and had to install all the apps anew.

I am bilingual and I used GBoard (Google Keyboard) on both, and on the old one I had it configured in such a way that it would automatically treat both languages I speak as one, so as I typed it would suggest words from both languages, even in the same sentence.

I can't figure out how to get that feature back on the new phone. It only ever suggests English words. How can I make it suggest words in both languages?

In GBoard settings -> Languages I have both languages installed and on both I have *Multilingual typing* enabled. Still it seems to make no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/165510

"On the the keyboard options you'll find settings for Languages, Preferences, Theme... and in Text correction you'll find the toggle you're looking for: multilingual typing."

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 it is here:
Latest Gboard moved the multilingual typing toggle to Languages > Language. There, each language defines whether it uses multilingual typing or not, and with which languages.

Answer (score 0):

Go to language → spelling check →  if it says that it's  system language, then go and click it and select the desired language. That way even if the Gboard has languages that don't support multilingual , you can still make it so that it can work with both languages