# One keyboard two languages using Gboard

Tags: gboard

Consider this, I want to add two languages on one keyboard with Gboard: English and French for QWERTY (English) keyboard. I open the settings but can't add language to the existing keyboard.

[image: only applicable if multi-languages are enabled]

(only applicable if multi-languages are enabled)

So to activate it I have to add another keyboard (English)

[image: multi-languages keyboard]

Now I have French support on the English keyboard and English support on the French keyboard. But I have two keyboards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What even is the point of this? And is there a way so that I can use only one keyboard (layout) with two languages?

Comment: Does [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203231/131553) answer help?

Comment: @beeshyams. No it didn't, I saw that before but none of the suggestions there resolved my issue. I think GBoard manage the system languages preference (as opposed of before when languages were configured outside of the app). So I guess there is no way to tell GBoard that a language exists without installing a new keyboard uh ? It's a shame bug in my opinion. They should check user preferences based on google general settings and make that option available afterward.

Comment: The point is that [the multilingual settings are not symmetric](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/165509/44325). You can enable French on the English keyboard but disable English on the French keyboard if you want. But answering the real question: AFAIK, with Gboard, no you can't. Maybe 3rd-party keyboards apps can (not yet researched), if you're okay with that.

Comment: Well I am not ok with that, though I will probably give SwiftKey a try. Again this is not a bug , but a very bad take in design here imo. And I think the reason many people didn't complain is because they usually use one or two keyboards with multi languages enabled so they don't switch often. But in my case I also have asian languages installed and having to press the switch key two times to jump over the "unused keyboard" is very annoying. Again they should give people the freedom to add a dual language on any wanted keyboard without having to install duplicates, this is the most sense.

Comment: Edit: I installed SwiftKey and as expected when I installed English and French (both qwerty layout) the two languages merged into one keyboard. I guess I will stick with that for some time.

Comment: Despite its popularity, I find Google's Gboard to be very lacking in many areas, as you have noticed as well. It also seems to store a massive amount of unknown data on the device.